# C# wrapper Java library generates strange code

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, heremaps-android-sdk

I have `Here` library written in `Java` for `Android` which I have wrapped to `C#` `Android` library

In `Java` there was the following code:

```java
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface LoadSceneCallback {
        void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapError var1);
    }
```

code in `Java` used as anonymous class:

```java
    mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapScheme.NORMAL_DAY, new MapScene.LoadSceneCallback() {
        ...
    }
```

`C#` wrapper generates the following code:

```cs
        // Metadata.xml XPath interface reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.here.sdk.mapview']/interface[@name='MapScene.LoadSceneCallback']"
        [Register ("com/here/sdk/mapview/MapScene$LoadSceneCallback", "", "Com.Here.Sdk.Mapview.MapScene/ILoadSceneCallbackInvoker")]
        public partial interface ILoadSceneCallback : IJavaObject, IJavaPeerable {

            // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.here.sdk.mapview']/interface[@name='MapScene.LoadSceneCallback']/method[@name='onLoadScene' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.here.sdk.mapview.MapError']]"
            [Register ("onLoadScene", "(Lcom/here/sdk/mapview/MapError;)V", "GetOnLoadScene_Lcom_here_sdk_mapview_MapError_Handler:Com.Here.Sdk.Mapview.MapScene/ILoadSceneCallbackInvoker, HereApi.Android")]
            void OnLoadScene (global::Com.Here.Sdk.Mapview.MapError p0);

        }
```

Actually I cannot figure out how to use it ... when I inherits from it I have to implement not only `void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapError var1)`, but also tones of `Java` methods ... :(

Have somebody faced with the same issue ? How to use such generated code

Comment: Is there a `JavaObject` you can inherit from to get most of that implementation?

Comment: @juharr In Java there is just anonymous class used, but what should be done on C# side ?

Comment: I mean does it include a C# class called something like `JavaObject` that implements most of the stuff in `IJavaObject`.

Comment: `JavaObject` does not help because it requires to implement `HandlePtr` ... instead I have used `Java.Lang.Object` and it solves my issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue with inheriting from `Java.Lang.Object` that implements most of boilerplate code

Also special thanks to @juharr for support !!